# Pass array to async library eachSeries - expects 'Dictionary<{}>'

Tags: arrays, node.js, typescript, async.js, typescript2.2

I have the following TypeScript code:

```
const allDescribeBlocks: Array<ITestSuite> = suman.allDescribeBlocks;

async.eachSeries(allDescribeBlocks, function (block: ITestSuite, cb: Function) {

//....

}, cb);
```

this will transpile with warnings:

> Argument of type ITestSuite[] is not assignable to parameter of type
>   Dictionary<{}>. Index signature is missing in ITestSuite[].

How to fix?

Here is the exact warning:[image]

Comment: From the name `Dictionary`, it seems to suggest it is expecting an object, not an array.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you installed the latest type definition for async library?

```
npm install --save @types/async
```

I just checked their source and it should accept both array and collection:

```
export function each<T, E>(arr: T[] | IterableIterator<T>, iterator: AsyncIterator<T, E>, callback?: ErrorCallback<E>): void;
export function each<T, E>(arr: Dictionary<T>, iterator: AsyncIterator<T, E>, callback?: ErrorCallback<E>): void;
export const eachSeries: typeof each;
```

I think if you install the type definition module and add the definition directory to your `tsconfig.json` using `"typeRoots": ["node_modules/@types"]`, it should solve the issue.

Edit - Also, you should avoid `Array<T>` definition for simple types and use `T[]` instead.